# Why choices CharField default value also defines DateField default value

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
# models.py
class Url(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOIX = [
        ('ATTENTE', 'ATTENTE'),
        ('VALIDE', 'VALIDE'),
        ('ERREUR', 'ERREUR'),
    ]
    URL = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    STATUS = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOIX, default='ATTENTE',)
    DATE = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    CIBLE = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Here is my model, when I try to save a Url object, I got this strange behaviour, DATE field gets STATUS's default value which is 'ATTENTE' instead of having the record creation date.

I have tried to swap **auto_now_add=True** with **default=date.today()** but I get the same problem.

Here is a print screen of what I have in database when I run the following code:

```py
from scrapper.models import Url

a = Url(URL="some_url", CIBLE="some-target")
a.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Normally it is impossible that a `DateField` even contains a non-date value. Did you properly migrate the database? What database do you use?

Comment: good point, I have just tried to rebuild my migrations and migrate again but the problem is still here. I am using sqlite

Comment: Ok problem solved, my SQL client sequeler works bad, I have tried with another one and date is fine.